# How to solve Landau-Lifshitz equation?

Tags: waves, ferromagnetism

In the macroscopic limit, spin oscillations are described by spin waves or magnetization waves. Often a formula given is Landau-Lifshitz equation:
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf M}{\partial t}= -\gamma\mathbf M \times\mathbf H - \frac{\lambda\mathbf M \times(\mathbf M \times\mathbf H)}{M^2}$$

where $\mathbf H$ is the magnetic field and $\mathbf M$. I wonder if this is even a wave equation (it does not have spatial derivatives). How does one solve this equation to look at the propagation of waves? How do I get the usual quadratic dispersion out of it?

Comment: Isn't Heisenberg's model more appropriate for [spin waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_wave)?

Comment: @lpz I am interested in the macroscopic dynamics...

Comment: This equation on its own does not describe propagation of waves, as you point out, there is no spatial coordinate. You need to use Maxwell's equations as well.

Comment: The Heisenberg model is already a coarse-grained model when viewed from the renormalisation group perspective. If you want waves, you need to allow spatial variations, which the LLG equation does not incorporate. The wave equations would verify the PDE in 1D:$$\partial_t S = S\times \partial_{xx}^2S$$

Comment: @lpz do you care to write an answer?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that's what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll rather treat the Heisenberg model, and everything will be classical. Recall that you have the Hamiltonian:
$$
H = -J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}S_i\cdot S_j-B\cdot \sum_i S_i
$$
with $|S_i|=1$. Note that $J,B$ are not necessarily the microscopic couplings, but rather effective couplings obtained after many coarse-graining. This equation is therefore macroscopic while incorporating spatial variations.

You have the equation of motion:
$$
\dot S_i = S_i\times\left(B+J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}S_j\right)
$$
which in the continuum limit becomes:
$$
\partial_t S = S\times(B+J\Delta S)
$$
with $\Delta$ the Laplacian, and in dimension $D=1$, $\Delta=\partial_{xx}^2$.

To see the waves, you look at linear stability analysis about the  equilibrium state which minimizes $H$. When $B\neq 0$, it is a uniform polarity:
$$
S_0 = \frac{B}{|B|}
$$
Writing $S = S_0+s$, I get:
$$
\partial_t s = S_0\times(B+J\Delta s)+s\times B
$$
Since the PDE is space and time independent, I can do a Fourier transform:
$$
s(t,x) = \int\frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D}\hat s(t,k) e^{ikx)}
$$
giving:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d\hat s}{dt} &= S_0\times(B-Jk^2 \hat s)+\hat s\times B \\
&=-\left(\frac{Jk^2}{|B|}+1\right)B\times \hat s
\end{align}
$$
Thus $\hat s$ precesses uniformly with angular velocity:
$$
\omega = -\left(\frac{Jk^2}{|B|}+1\right)B
$$
The perturbations are therefore superpositions of excitations of the form:
$$
s = R[-(Jk^2+B)t]s_0e^{ikx}
$$
where $R[\phi]$ is a rotation about the direction $B/|B|$ of angle $\phi$. These solutions are not spin waves, since the time dependent rotation and space dependent phase are separated, there is no propagation. Spin waves are obtained by superposing two modes of opposing wave vectors. They form another basis of modes and are given by:
$$
s = R[-(Jk^2+B)t\pm kx]s_0
$$
You now can analogously define the phase velocity:
$$
v_\phi = \frac{\omega}{|k|^2}k
$$
as well as the group velocity:
$$
v_g = \nabla_k \omega
$$

Things are slightly different when $B=0$. The minimum is degenerate, and any uniform polarity $S_0$ will do. The result is now that $\hat s$ precesses uniformly:
$$
\omega = -Jk^2 S_0
$$
so you again get spin waves. I think that this is the quadratic dispersion you were looking for. Note the gap is proportional to $|B|$, and therefore vanishes in this case, as expected by Goldstone's theorem.

Hope this helps.